# Error getting products from the logged in user. ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having trouble getting only products purchased by the logged in user, that is, the user who made the purchase.

I have a `Users` table that contains general registration data, and a `Customers` table.

The relationship between the tables is as follows:

- `User`: userId, name, email, password
- `Customer`: customerId, status, section_id, user_id
- `Product`: productId, name, price, purchase_date, customer_id

Well, the `Products` table is related to the `Customers` table and not to the `Users` table. And I can't change that because there are other applications consulted in the database.

I try to get the products this way, but the id value of `Customer` is null.

```
public IActionResult View(int id)
{
    User user = _loginUser.GetUser();
    Product product = _pedidoRepository.GetProduct(id);

    if (product.customer_id != user.Customer.customerId)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "Access denied" };
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

I get the error:

> Project.Models.users.Customer.get returned null

How can I make the `Client` id accessible for comparison purposes?

My `GetUser` method looks like this:

```
public user GetUser()
{
    // Deserializar
    if( _session.Exists(Key)) 
    {
        string user JSONString = _session.Consult(Key);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<user>(userJSONString);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is important to say that the relationship between "User" and "Customer" is one by one. When registering "User", "Customer" is registered in the table with a fk for "User"

Class User.cs

```
public class User
{
    /* PK */
    [Key]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email{ get; set; }
    public string passwor{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("user_id")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Class Customer.cs

```
public class Customer
{
    /* PK */
    [Key]
    public int customerId{ get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
   
    [Column("user_id")]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int? user_id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
```

Class Product.cs

```
public class Product
{
    /* PK */
    [Key]
    public int productId{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public DateTime  purchase_date { get; set; }

    [Column("customer_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int? customer_id{ get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate any comments. I'm starting with language. If I need to, I can send some more codes.

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]` try removing this from customer property of User class

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed it, but the student's value remains nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would assume that your session holds a JSON representation of user, queried at some point from the DB. When this happens, user is queried without the Customer navigational property (so it's null). When you access later User.Customer, User entity is not attached to DbContext anymore, therefore Customer is not loaded from the DB.
If my assumtion is true, I'd propose two options:

1. When filling the session object, query user with loaded customer, like `context.Users.Include(c => c.Customer).GetById(x)`
2. In your method query Customer from the DB using userId. I.e. you get User from session, but matching Customer from the DB.

The choice depends on whether Cutomer is relevant for most of your calls or just for this single one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was it! Now I can get the student's value, but now I have the error: 'Self-reference loop detected for the' User 'property with the type' Project.Models.User '. path 'Customer'. I will look for a solution. Thank you!

Comment: You user references customer and customer references user, so you have a loop. You have to tell EF explicitely, which relation is this: one-to-one, one-to-zero-one, etc., which is the main entity (i.e. in which table the FK should be placed) and what to do on deletion. See e.g. here https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx